# I/O System Calls

Tags: c, file-io, segmentation-fault, system-calls

I am learning system calls as part of lab in my undergrad course. In my OS lab I started getting this error repeatedly even though I am unable to find any error in the program code.

### *Terminal output*

```
bharaths-mbp:sem4 bharathdustan$ vim readFromFile.c  
bharaths-mbp:sem4 bharathdustan$ gcc readFromFile.c  
bharaths-mbp:sem4 bharathdustan$ ./a.out  
Segmentation fault: 11
```

*The code for which I received this error was :*

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("file1.dat","r");
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%s",str);
        printf(" %s ",str);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Can anyone help me find the error in the said program?

Comment: compile with -g option and try to use gdb

Comment: Check if fopen returns null.

Comment: Check string in your file is not more than 99 chars.

Comment: You should check the return value from fopen. The problem is almost certainly that you can't open the file. Then your feof loop is wrong, but that won't crash the program. And to nitpick: fopen, fscanf etc aren't system calls, they're library functions.

Answer (score 1):

1) Check the result of `fopen()`

```
fp = fopen("file1.dat", "r");
if (fp == NULL) Handle_FileOpenError();
```

2) Need to check the result of `fscanf()` or `feof()` after the read.  `feof()` does not return true until after a read with no result occurs.  Original code checked `feof()` too late.

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%s",str) != EOF) {
    printf(" %s ",str);
}
```

3) As @Rohan suggest, insure you are not overfilling `str`

```
while(fscanf(fp,"%99s",str) != EOF) {
    printf(" %s ",str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing semantically wrong with your code it just isn't very secure or flexible. If the file isn't found (make sure it's in the same directory) then you could get a segfault and if the string you read in is greater than the memory allocated you could segfalut. If both of these things are covered then I don't see any reason why it should segfault.